# The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a problem with NonNullable feature of Dart

```
double? totalSum;
```

this is my variable that I will initialize later I used late key word also it also doesn't work

Here is the variable assigned

```
for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
    if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
        recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
        recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
      totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
    }
  }
```

Error is on this line
[image]

suggesting
[image]

if I remove ? from my variable assign section it will give error saying
Non Nullable  must be assigned before using

Comment: This  would look a lot cleaner with a List.map rather than indexing multiple times in to the List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring totalSum as non-nullable like:

```
double totalSum = 0;
```

or

```
totalSum! += recentTransactions[i].amount;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you initializing the value anywhere before the `+` call ?
Otherwise you are just adding to null on the first call.
If you are initializing with a non null value before that line somewhere, you call add `!` to your totalSum on the line where you use +=.

Otherwise as Josteve said, just mark as non nullable with an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double totalSum = 0;
```